# Getting a Wordpress PHP Fatal Error with REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have installed a Redirection plugin for my site and unfortunately I see a Critical Error and REST API is not working. Upon checking the debug file here is the error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_REST_Block_Patterns_Controller' not found in /home/casinotructuyen/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api.php:341

[image]

But I checked the rest-api file and it is there. What am I missing here?

[rest api screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rebo8.jpg)

This happened right after upgrading wordpress version.

Comment: Well it cant be or you would not be getting this error. Can you show us the code that makes you think it is there

Comment: hi i edited my post and included a link to my rest api screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rebo8.jpg

Comment: As I suspected, that is code to instantiate a class into an object. When the Class is unknown (missing) you get this error

Comment: can you help shed some light on this issue? Do I need to add anything?
 I never touched these files before.